# Woocommerce custom variations view?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom variations view at product page. It is a [simple colorboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERpei.png). I hide default woocommerce variations selects and than change it after click on box:

```
jQuery('.colors-list li').on('click', function(event){
       if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
           //change active square
           jQuery('.colors-list .active').removeClass('active');
           jQuery(this).addClass('active');
           //change active color label
           var colorName = jQuery(this).attr('colorname');
           jQuery('.checked-color').html(colorName);
           //change value of hided woocommerce variable switcher
           var colorSlug = jQuery(this).attr('colorval');
           jQuery('#pa_color').val(colorSlug).change();
              jQuery('.variations_form').trigger('woocommerce_variation_select_change');
       }
    });
```

But once I change only one select(color), for this reason I have an error in js(add_to_cart variation.js):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Error at this:

```
if ( $( this ).val().length === 0 ) .
```

If I have only one variations - error does not occur. I tried to change second select with color to default value, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a plugin [Woocommerce Radio Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-radio-buttons/) and make similar